# What type of mirror is feasible for Schlieren photography setup?

Tags: optics, reflection

I would like to build a Schlieren photography system with a single mirror setup<sup>*</sup>. My question is - what type of mirror (parabolic/spherical) is good or at least feasible for this setup?

The theory says that spherical mirror is the right choice since a point source is needed to be focused back to a point at similar position. However, parabolic mirrors are easier to find and get and some people seem to use them. My question is - **what conditions need to be met so that a parabolic mirror is sufficient?** I'm loking for data - focal lengths, mirror diameters, etc. Personal experience counts.

Thanks for any answers.

---

<sup>*</sup>light from a point source goes through the tested area onto a mirror, is reflected, goes through the tested area again, is focused into to a single point where there is a knife edge and then ends up in camera

Answer (score 1):

A [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Schlieren+photography+parabolic+spherical) turns up a lot of info. As you say, spherical mirror is preferred in single mirror setup. Parabolic not too bad for longer focal lengths (although I didn't see the math done anywhere), but that means a longer lens on the camera and a larger room.

(I found these ["poor man's" methods](http://jonathan.lansey.net/pastimes/schlier/). I want to try the second one.)

Comment: Seems I didn't phrase my question accurately. My main concern was about when it is sufficient to use parabolic mirror and when the difference between sphere and a parabola is big enough to cause troubles. I'll edit my question. But thanks for the links nevertheless. I got tied up in a lot of other google searches and in the end I failed in doing such a simple search.

Comment: There are some telescope related tags at http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: You could also try http://photo.stackexchange.com/. BTW, spherical mirrors are easier/cheaper to manufacture than parabolic and they seem to be widely available.

Comment: I did try the ["poor man's method"](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/synthetic-schlieren-imaging.963142/), using checkerboard patterns instead of noise. Checkerboards for various resolutions are given.